# Ajax jquery success:funtion ejecutar una function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

```
success:function(data) {
        $('#login').val("Login");
        if (data=="1") {
         $(location).attr('href','index.php');

        } else {
          swal("Error", "Datos Icorrectos)", "error");
        }
      }
```

quiero mostrar el siguiene codigo en el html despues del success

```
$.notify({
  message: 'Hello World' 
},{
  type: 'danger'
});
```

Comment: No veo el duplicado por ningún lado...

Answer (score 1):

aqui la solución :
usa $(elemento).text(); de jQuery para mostrar codigo html o javascript

```
success:function(data) {
    $(elementoHTML).text("$.notify({message: 'Hello World' },{  type: 'danger'});");
    $('#login').val("Login");
    if (data=="1") {
     $(location).attr('href','index.php');

    } else {
      swal("Error", "Datos Icorrectos)", "error");
    }
  }
```

Saludos...

Comment: Gracias pero quisiera imprimir eso en las etiquetas <script></script>

Answer (score 0):

El método `success()` es obsoleto a partir de jQuery 3.0, por lo que te sugiero que utilices `done()`.

Teniendo en cuenta que estás usando el plugin [notify.js](https://notifyjs.com/), no necesitas incluir las etiquetas script, lo que asumo que quieres es ejecutarlo cuando la solicitud ajax sea exitosa:

```
$.ajax('...').
  done(function(data) {

    $.notify({
      message: 'Hello World' 
    },{
      type: 'danger'
    });

    $('#login').val("Login");
    if (data=="1") {
      $(location).attr('href','index.php');
    } else {
      swal("Error", "Datos Incorrectos)", "error");
    }
  });
```

Comment: A no ser que se me escapa algo ... en el sitio jQuery no dice nada que el método success() es obsoleto : http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-3.0/
Tampoco en : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/